# Demora en obtener la dirección IP en KVM via virsh

Tags: bash

Estoy armando un script en bash para automatizar la creación de VMs en KVM, y cuando utilizo virsh para obtener la dirección IP que me entrega el DHCP, demora alrededor de 70 segundos para actualizar, entonces en mi script, no me responde en tiempo para automatizarlo, y la verdad como quiero crear muchas vms a la vez, no quiero tener que esperar 2 minutos con sleep por cada vm creada.

los comandos de virsh que probe (los pego sin parsear) fueron:

```
$ virsh net-dhcp-leases default --mac $vmMAC

$ ip neigh | grep -i $vmMAC
```

Ambos comandos me funcionan para obtener la información, pero dicha demora rompe el funcionamiento de mis script.

Necesito saber como "preguntarle a KVM o como forzar para que actualice la tabla de DHCP. La vm que estoy prendiendo, demora 5 segundos en obtener una IP.

PD: El sistema operativo es fedora 30. 
PD2: Es mi primer preguna en stack y espero su buena voluntad al criticar :D

---

Hasta ahora la solución mas prolija que encontré es correr un nmap -sP a todo el segmento para que la tabla de arp se actualice. Ahora anda, no es prolijo pero funciona.
Ideas?

Comment: Si no hay ningún otro comando para conseguir estos datos, lo suyo será esperar que termine el comando para proceder, ¿no?